# Most minimalist way to build a scroller for interactive storytelling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to build a static but responsive storytelling HTML website. My goal is to achieve something likes this:
[image]

**Text on the left, *.jpg image with a fixed position on the right. As a user scrolls the text on the left side, the image on the right side remains fixed in position but changes to another *.jpg image with a short transition, after the scrolling on the left side has reached a certain point.**

*Responsive in this case would means that I'm completely satisfied with the sticky scrolling being inactive on smaller screens and the text and image block simply returning to their normal breakpoint behaviour.*

I have looked into various Storytelling and scrolling JavaScript libraries (Scrollstory, Waypoints and InView) to achieve this goal simply, lightweight and easy. All of them (so far) seem completely overengineered for what I'm trying to do.

The barely available tutorials and code snippets make me feel a little bit like this:

[image: htm]

I find no real reference that tells me how to get started with small steps to build a scroller in the first place. Regardless of the library.

Reference files of the individual libraries (that have accessible code) are often outdated and focus on working with external data visualization frameworks and require loading up to four other external scripts for whatever reason and still provide no responsive functionality.

I've tried to rebuild this showcase example here: https://russellgoldenberg.github.io/scrollama/sticky-side/ because it is at least half of what I want to achieve, but I couldn't get it to work and I don't understand the excessive use of JavaScript there either:  https://jsfiddle.net/gdkupcb6/2/

```
  <article>
<div class='step' data-step='1'>
  <p>STEP 1</p>
</div>
<div class='step' data-step='2'>
  <p>STEP 2</p>
</div>
<div class='step' data-step='3'>
  <p>STEP 3</p>
</div>
<div class='step' data-step='4'>
  <p>STEP 4</p>
</div>
```

The code looks easy enough on the HTML side and makes sense to me on almost all libraries, but I get completely lost when it comes to the JavsScript part. Why do I need D3 here? Why so much JS functionalities for a simple change on scroll?

Am I completely wrong in my belief that there is a minimalist way to achieve such a rather simple sticky scrolling without involving multiple different external scripts and libraries?

Can someone point me in a good direction to build a scroller step by step that allows me to understand each part of the code that get's in and not under the involvement of complex external libraries and tutorials that seem to have no real beginning and no end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use JavaScript - you add a window.addEventListener("wheel") or "scroll" and listen when your "picture".offsetTop gets to the right scroll position and turn position to of this element to "fixed". Also, you can optionally add a "slow motion in" effect or just play with how image scrolls with the page.

Your jsFiddle didnt work for me, but I like the idea so I plugged a little 30 lines of code [---DEMO---](https://codepen.io/sanchopanza/pen/xxxQPEL) on codepen for a similar purpose of this idea, its a little clunky will gladly take any advice from others, but it works.
Atm it scrolls the image with your page seemingly changing images when chunks of text start and finish (I use emojies instead of images, but the idea is the same).

It should automatically scale to your screen sizes while still working, but it's untested so ..:D

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var stickyImage = document.getElementById("stickyImage");
var tempY;
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
//watch how image moves with scrolleing
    if(window.pageYOffset >= container.offsetTop && window.pageYOffset <= container.offsetTop+container.offsetHeight  - window.innerHeight ){
        console.log("slinding");
        stickyImage.style.position = "fixed";
        stickyImage.style.top = "0vh";
        stickyImage.style.marginTop = "";
        tempY = window.pageYOffset;
    }else if(window.pageYOffset <= container.offsetTop){
        console.log("top sxcreen");
        stickyImage.style.position = "absolute";
        stickyImage.style.top = "";
        stickyImage.style.marginTop = "";       
    }else{
        console.log("stop");
        stickyImage.style.position = "absolute";
        stickyImage.style.marginTop = tempY + "px";         
    }
//change images while scroll
    if(window.pageYOffset < document.getElementById("change1").offsetTop){
        stickyImage.textContent = "";
    }
    if(window.pageYOffset > document.getElementById("change1").offsetTop){
        stickyImage.textContent = "";
    }
    if(window.pageYOffset > document.getElementById("change2").offsetTop){
        stickyImage.textContent = "";
    }   
})
```

Comment: Mr. Panza I'll guess I owe you a coffee (if not more) because those 30 lines of code just saved me an enormous amount of work & trouble. A big plus have been your annotations in JS that helped me understand how and why you used functions. Something that is deeply missing in most, if not all, storytelling libraries.

Could I buzz you with a short follow-up question?

Comment: yeah sure go-ahead

Comment: Thank you!

My question is: how would you keep the sticky.Image in it's position and have only the text scrollable, while the images still change after reaching the text start and finishes? 

As an example: https://pitchfork.com/features/cover-story/reader/daft-punk/
In the 2 column layout - images stay in place and  only the text scrolls while images change after reaching a text start.

Comment: not sure what you talking about..the image in the background? Btw there is another way to do it a little prettier I guess is with window.requestAnimationFrame() , and use this loop function to listen and animate images, etc.  https://codepen.io/sanchopanza/pen/XWWyQqx here is some smoother entrance I was talking about and images fade-in on scroll

Answer (score 2):

First , for your code to work you need to wrap it with main tag.

```js
// using d3 for convenience
var main = d3.select('main')
var scrolly = main.select('#scrolly');
var figure = scrolly.select('figure');
var article = scrolly.select('article');
var step = article.selectAll('.step');

// initialize the scrollama
var scroller = scrollama();

// generic window resize listener event
function handleResize() {
  // 1. update height of step elements
  var stepH = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.75);
  step.style('height', stepH + 'px');

  var figureHeight = window.innerHeight / 2
  var figureMarginTop = (window.innerHeight - figureHeight) / 2

  figure
    .style('height', figureHeight + 'px')
    .style('top', figureMarginTop + 'px');


  // 3. tell scrollama to update new element dimensions
  scroller.resize();
}

// scrollama event handlers
function handleStepEnter(response) {

  // response = { element, direction, index }

  // add color to current step only
  step.classed('is-active', function(d, i) {
    return i === response.index;
  })

  // update graphic based on step
  figure.select('p').text(response.index + 1);
}

function setupStickyfill() {
  d3.selectAll('.sticky').each(function() {
    Stickyfill.add(this);
  });
}

function init() {
  setupStickyfill();

  // 1. force a resize on load to ensure proper dimensions are sent to scrollama
  handleResize();

  // 2. setup the scroller passing options
  //   this will also initialize trigger observations
  // 3. bind scrollama event handlers (this can be chained like below)
  scroller.setup({
      step: '#scrolly article .step',
      offset: 0.33,
      debug: true,
    })
    .onStepEnter(handleStepEnter)


  // setup resize event
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
}

// kick things off
init();
```

```css
 #scrolly {
   position: relative;
   display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
   padding: 1rem;
  }

  #scrolly > * {
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
     -ms-flex: 1;
     flex: 1;
  }


  article {
   position: relative;
   padding: 0 1rem;
   max-width: 20rem;
  }

  figure {
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   background-color: #8a8a8a;
  }

  figure p {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1rem;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   font-size: 8rem;
   font-weight: 900;
   color: #fff;
  }


  .step {
   margin: 0 auto 2rem auto;
   background-color: #3b3b3b;
   color: #fff;
  }

  .step:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .step.is-active {
   background-color: goldenrod;
   color: #3b3b3b;
  }

  .step p {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1rem;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<main>

<section id='intro'>
  <h1 class='intro__hed'>Sticky Side Example</h1>
  <p class='intro__dek'>
    Start scrolling to see how it works.
  </p>
</section>

<section id='scrolly'>

  <article>
    <div class='step' data-step='1'>
      <p>STEP 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class='step' data-step='2'>
      <p>STEP 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class='step' data-step='3'>
      <p>STEP 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class='step' data-step='4'>
      <p>STEP 4</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <figure>
    <p>0</p>
  </figure>
</section>
</main>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/intersection-observer@0.5.1/intersection-observer.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollama"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/d3@5.9.1/dist/d3.min.js'></script>
```

Second, i don't see any other alternative solution besides using javascript. Especially if there is already libraries like scrollama that does the work for you.

Normally , JS code make the page more dynamic. For example  : Only CSS + HTML can't change an image background depending on the position of the div.

I'll respond to you you in comments for more infos. I'll try my best to help ^^

Comment: Hey - Wow thank you so much!  Wrapping the code into the <main> tag did get the JsFiddle to work.

I do get the advantages that JS provides, I'm just wondering if whether or not the intersection observber and D3 are really needed. 

What is your take on this suggestion of using position:sticky via CSS?
https://pudding.cool/process/scrollytelling-sticky/